# Static folder problems on multiple apps project on django

Tags: python, css, django, static

I'm new on Django and I have some problems with the static folder.

I created a "static folder" on the project root and inside I put folders for each app.

Django admin page is charging correctly
But CSS, JS, images and others on my index isn't.

How can I avoid have this problems in the future? For your answers, thank you so much.

`settings.py`

[image]

I set the `{% load static %}` in my html document

and i write the static tag like this example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'principal/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot this => <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'principal/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css">

Answer (score 0):

Yo haven't created **STATIC_DIRS** where the django will find CSS,javascript files and the create the **STATIC_ROOT** where the django will store all the files
then run **python manage.py collectstatic**  to let setup all the files